How do I click change the country to a new one from the COUNTRY/REGION section using Selenium Webdriver
I am building a web scrapper but I want to be able to switch the country to another using Selenium.
For instance I want to be able to click on the country button and select a new country or region?
The code of what I have done so far
The code above just scrolls to the button but is not clicking it so that i can have the option to select a different country or region. Please help.
Here is the code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import logging
import time

# Adjusting logging levels
logging.getLogger('urllib3').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
logging.getLogger('selenium').setLevel(logging.WARNING)


# Set up Selenium with Chrome in headless mode (if needed)
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')  # Uncomment if you want to run headless
#chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
#chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

# Navigating the Gucci France Store
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options= chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.gucci.com/za/en_gb/")

try:
    # Wait for the consent button to be present
    consent_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'onetrust-accept-btn-handler'))  
)
    consent_button.click()

    # Wait until the button containing "South Africa" is present
    south_africa_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[.//span[text()='South Africa']]"))
    )
    south_africa_button.click()

    #Select the United State Store
    un_store = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[.//span[text() = "United States"]]'))
    )
    un_store.click()

except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
finally:
    driver.quit()


Please post the code as text, not a screenshot.

I have added the code. thanks
